# Call 7zip from Python on Windows

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to invoke 7zip, on Windows, from a Python program.

I'm trying:

```
 stdout = subprocess.run(['C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe', "a -t7z -mx0", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test.7z", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test.txt", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test2.txt"], shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
 print(stdout)
```

but am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Normal Backup\Code\ProcessRetrospectBackups\process.py", line 93, in <module>
    stdout = subprocess.run(['C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe', "a -t7z -mx0", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test.7z", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test.txt", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test2.txt"], shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout

  File "C:\Users\IanWo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe', 'a -t7z -mx0', 'C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test.7z', 'C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test.txt', 'C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test2.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 7.
>>>
```

It invokes `7z.exe` fine as long as I don't have any arguments. I've tried with and without `shell=True` with no change.

Comment: `a -t7z -mx0` - put each argument in its own list item... otherwise you pass them as a single arg containing these literal spaces, which won't work.

Comment: @ThiefMaster  That's it.  Many thanks.  Any feelings about if I should be using or avoiding shell under windows??

Comment: Never use `shell=True` unless you really need a shell. In most cases you don't.

Answer (score 2):

@ThiefMaster is right.  Here's the correct call:

```
stdout = subprocess.run(['C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe', "a", "-t7z", "-mx0", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test.7z", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test.txt", "C:\\Users\\IanWo\\test2.txt"], shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
print(stdout)
```